# Insert an additional <div> after wrapped on navwalker

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-walker

So I'm having some issues and I can't figure out how to solve them, I've recently started working with `WordPress navwalkers` and I'm stuck on a particular piece and I can't figure out how to get around it.

So I am using the Bulma Framework inside a wordpress theme.

Here is my current output:

[image]

Here is what I'm attempting to achieve (Please give me criticism if you have any, I'm still learning) - I just can't figure out how to add in an extra div to wrap after the first `$depth`:

[image]

Here is my `wp_nav_menu` header:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-menu is-active">
                    <div class="navbar-start" id="main-navigation">
                        <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( [
                            'theme_location' => 'primary',
                            'depth' => 3,
                            'container' => true,
                            'items_wrap' => '%3$s', // Removes the <ul>
                            'walker' => new Nav_walker(),
                        ]);
                        ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Here is the navwalker code**:

```
class Nav_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string $output
     * @param int $depth
     * @param array $args
     */
    public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = [])
    {
        // Indent the items
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

        // The first <div> inside mega-menu
        if ($depth == 0) {
            $output .= "\n$indent<div class='navbar-dropdown'>\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "<div id=\"nav-items\">";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string $output
     * @param int $depth
     * @param array $args
     */
    public function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = [])
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</div>\n";
    }

    /**
     * Start the element output
     *
     * @param string $output
     * @param WP_Post $item
     * @param int $depth
     * @param array $args
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = [], $id = 0)
    {
        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';

        // Define all the menu-item classes
        $classes = empty($item->classes) ? [] : (array) $item->classes;

        // Combine the class names
        $class_names = implode(' ', $item->classes);

        // Add in the navbar-item class
        $class_names .= ' navbar-item';

        // Add in the active class to current menu item
        if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
            $class_names .= ' active';
        }

        // Check if there are children
        $hasChildren = $args->walker->has_children;

        // If it's the first depth, apply the needed classes
        if ($depth === 0) {
            $class_names .= $hasChildren ? " has-dropdown is-hoverable" : "";
        }

        // If it's the second depth, apply the needed classes
        if ($depth === 1) {
            $class_names .= ' column is-3';
        }

        // Apply the needed class markup
        $class_names = $class_names ? 'class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';

        // If there are children, continue to apply elements
        if ($hasChildren) {
            $output .= "<div " . $class_names . ">";

            if ($depth === 0) {
                $output .= "<div class='navbar-link'>" . $item->title . "</div>";
            } else {
                $output .= "<h1 class='title is-6 is-mega-menu-title'>" . $item->title . "</h1>";
            }
        }
        else {
            $output .= "<a class='navbar-item' href='" . $item->url . "'>" . $item->title;
        }

        // Adds has_children class to the item so end_el can determine if the current element has children
        if ($hasChildren) {
            $item->classes[] = 'has_children';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output
     *
     * @param string $output
     * @param WP_Post $item
     * @param int $depth
     * @param array $args
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 )
    {
        if (in_array("has_children", $item->classes)) {
            $output .= "</div>";
        }
        $output .= "</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the output you are getting to your question please. Indeed i'd like to see if there is any change at all.

Comment: @GetSet, the output is the screenshot that I included, which is what's being rendered with the wordpress menu.

Comment: Actually i am more interested in the *actual* output, not the desired output at this point. Can you include in your question the actual output in code form? Your screenshot is what you want, not what you have.

Comment: Your `start_lvl` starts out with depth == 0. So does your actual output even have the inserted opening `div`? Helps to see what you really have, not just a nice graphic on what you want.

Comment: @GetSet, the screenshot includes what I currently have without the red added remarks, the only addon that I want is to have `<div class="columns"> wrapped around the `<div class="navbar-item">`'s

Comment: @GetSet Let me upload a new screenshot with what I currently have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221797/discussion-between-semir-smajlovic-and-getset).

Comment: Listen i must remind you that it is *you* who have the logical error. Your question needs more debugging details. We can simply delete our comments on this once you post what you actually have. No need for chat at this moment.

Comment: @GetSet, apologies! I updated the post with my current output.

Comment: I followed your chat link. We can discuss there, this might get too long here

Comment: Solved in chat... For anyone curious